# How to iterate an array and acces a map using Handlebars?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have data structures similar to the code below that I want to iterate through with Handlerbars. While the javascript code that can do this iteration is clear, I have not been able to figure out how to do it in handlebars.

```
var keys = ['key1','key2','key3'] 
var map = {'key1':{...}, 'key2':{...}, 'key3':{...}, .... 'keyN': {...}}
```

What I want to do within handlebars is to iterate the keys array and use the value from the keys array to look-up the object from the map. Can this be done without writing a helper?

**UPDATE** I know how to write the code in javascript, I want to do is "what i can do in raw js using handlebarJS expressions".

Comment: My apologies, still working on the coffee. Apparently [tag:handlebars.js] doesn't standout as much as it should pre-coffee.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
for(var i=0; i<keys.length; i++){
   console.log(map[keys[i]])
}

Handlebars.registerHelper('list', function(keys, maps) {
  var out = "<ul>";

  for(var i=0, i=keys.length; i++) {
    out = out + "<li>" + map[keys[i]] + "</li>";
  }

  return out + "</ul>";
});
```

Comment: Can this be made generic so that in Handlebars its written something along the lines of {{get {{key}} }} is that even possible? Its important that the helper just get the object without doing the processing in the hepler. I am really new to Handlebars

Comment: i think you still need to iterate object or array after map[keys[i]].